# Unable to locate package php5-curl

Tags: php, linux, curl, lamp

I have a Linux server with Ubuntu 16.04 installed. I usit just for LAMPP environment, I have PHP 5.6 installed (in apache and CLI), that because the project crash with PHP7, so, I have to maintain in 5.6 version. I'm trying to run a PHP script from the CLI, and I gets: curl_init() in unkown function.
So, I went to the php.ini file (the one of the CLI) and unable the extension, but in CLI when I make: `php --version` I get:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_curl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/php_curl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Then I tried to install curl with: `sudo apt-get install php5-curl` but then I get:

```
E: Unable to locate package php5-curl
```

So, what should I do then? How can I install it?thanks

Answer (score 8):

I got the same issue you need to add this repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
```

Answer (score 5):

try running i have same issue solved by this command

```
 sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

Comment: yes, I already made that and everything perfect. Then in the console I typed: `curl --help` and its installed. So I'm starting to believe that I hace to replace the directory where the dll is located, but I don't know how to find the current location

Comment: on ubuntu terminal curl is already install but we have to enable it in php.ini file you can build a page which show phpinfo() function and on top you will see directory where you have to include the code  as in my mechine that is /etc/php/7.0/apache2

Answer (score 1):

In **Ubuntu 16.04** default **PHP version is 7.0**, if you want to use different version then you need to install PHP package according to PHP version:

```
1-> PHP 7.0: sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl
2-> PHP 7.1: sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl
3-> PHP 7.2: sudo apt-get install php7.2-curl
4-> PHP 5.5: sudo apt-get install php5.5-curl
5-> PHP 5.6: sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl
```

Answer (score 1):

1. add this repository

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`

   `sudo apt update`
2. select your php version 5.5, 5.6,7.0, 7.2

   PHP 5.6: `sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl`
3. Test curl enabled or disabled

   create index.php and add this code

   `echo 'Curl: ', function_exists('curl_init') ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled';`